# Arquillian with Junit, Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have this all dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

, and i get java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor. Am i missing some more dependencies?

I tried to add some more depenedecies but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get a similar problem with Arquillian 1.7.0.Final/JUnit 4.12 when I migrated my environment to Java17 with JakartaEE. The solution that worked for me was to upgrade to Junit5.